# Как хранить в базе данных объекты с переменным число полей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb

Проектирую базу данных. В ней должны храниться несколько сотен тысяч объектов с уникальными `id`, назначенными извне.

1) Первая проблема в том, что у объектов переменное число полей. И это число и значения полей каждый день меняются.

2) Информация, как я уже написал, каждый день обновляется. Значения за предыдущие дни должны тоже храниться в базе. Число объектов остаётся постоянным.

Я временно сделал одну большую таблицу. Но это же неправильно, так как много полей пустует.

Comment: Влад, а выборки возможны прям по всем всем полям? Переменное количество полей можно пихать в json. Последние версии СУБД поддерживали выборки по полям даже с ним.

Comment: Да, выборки будут по полям. Сортировка, графики изменения значений полей по дням и тд. Я уже в сторону монги смотрел, но вникать не хочется. Да и реляционные бд как-то больше мне по душе))

Comment: Мысль есть общую таблицу для всех полей сделать - `ключ` | `значение` | `дата` | `id объекта`. `ключ` | `название поля` - хранить в другой таблице. А для объектов получается только таблица айдишников? Не знаю, правильно это или нет))

Comment: или для каждого поля свою таблицу создавать? и туда записывать айди объекта, дату и значение?)) Короче ума не приложу как сделать.

Comment: В одной таблице `id` + общие поля. В другой `id` родительского поля, `имя` поля(колонка `key`), значение (`value`)

Comment: Одно слово "EAV" (прямо по нему можно искать). Собственно это именно то о чем вы и подумали в комментах. ее можно как то немного развивать, как вы например добавили дату. Но суть для реляционных БД остается всегда около такой модели, другого пути нет. Для поиска - отлично, вывод конкретного показателя - отлично, выборка всех данных об объекте - медленно, иногда приходится задумываться о кешировании и хранении _копии_ всех данных например в виде json в таблице с самим объектом.

Comment: @Mike Почитал, спасибо. Только не совсем понял - в таблице значений будет же текстовое поле типа varchar получается для всех значений - int, decimal и тд. а как потом сортировать, считать и тд. То есть с численными значениями работать как с числами? Они же как строки будут представлены.

Comment: @Vlad Об этом постоянно споры идут и единого мнения нет. кто то хранит в одном поле varchar, кто то делает несколько полей разных типов и заполняет одно из них. Я обычно склоняюсь все таки к первому. проблемы возникнут только при сортировке по числовому значению в строке и сравнениях больше/меньше и тогда его придется явно конвертить. В одной системе у меня все возможные хранимые строки были перечислимыми типами и тогда я для строк сделал отдельный справочник и хранил в EAV id этих строк и поле было int (decimal у меня не было)

Comment: @Mike понял, спасибо большое.